# Add basic http authentication info in a servlet

Tags: servlets, filter, http-authentication

I have a servlet out of the secured area. I want to add Basic Http Authentication info (so the "Authorization: Basic asdasdmasdjsankj" header and forward the flow to the index page.
Obviously the forward will be intercepted by the basic http auth filter and the others site page are secured.
If I access directly to the index page the browser asks me for user and password (and this is right).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure basic authentication in the `web.xml` file. See tip 5 here: http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html

Also covered here: [Tomcat basic auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014619/tomcat-basic-auth)